# Probability involving mean time failure

Tags: probability, statistics

Accidents occur in a factory at the rate of 2 per week. Assume that accidents happen randomly and independently of each other.

I'm not sure my answers are correct but I'll show my work so far:

**a) What is the probability that the time to the first accident is greater than 2 weeks?**

$P(X > 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) + P(X = 1)$

$1-\left(\frac{2^1}{e 1!}+\frac{2^0}{e^2 0!}\right) = .129$

**b) What is the probability that the time to the first accident is less than 2 days (2/7 week)?**

$P(X < 2) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1)$

$\frac{2^1}{e 1!}+\frac{2^0}{e^2 0!}\ = .871$

I'm also asked to find the mean time to the first accident and the variance of the time to the first accident but am unsure of how to approach that.

Comment: Do you know about exponentially distributed random variables?

Comment: A problem with your two answers (which add up to $1$) is that (a) talks about two **weeks** while (b) talks about **two days**. There are several other problems: another is that $P(X \lt 2)$ as you have expressed it means the probability of fewer than two accidents in one week: you also have a small error in  $P(X=1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** The time to the first accident is a *continuous* random variable, not a discrete one. Try to model this with an **exponentially distributed** random variable, with the pdf
$$
f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, x > 0.
$$

Comment: Wilson could use the Poisson distribution by adjusting the rates: e.g. for (b) the accident rate is $\frac27$ in two days so $P(X \gt 0)=1-P(X=0)=1-\dfrac{(2/7)^0}{e^{2/7} 0!}$ would give the correct answer.